# Storing an image as a byte[] using import.sql with spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql

I'm trying to add an image file into a database using an `import.sql` file when `spring` is loaded. I'm currently using `postgresql`.

My byte array is in my `project` class:

```
 @Lob
 private byte[] bytes;
```

I've attempted to import the file via `pg_read_file` like so:

```
-- Insert into Project

insert into project (title, colour, description, project_user_id, bytes) values ('Test', '#F6D2B4', 'a short description of some project, making sure its over 50 characters', 1, pg_read_file('classpath:static/images/pon9s2N.jpg'))
```

but I get the following error when running spring:

```
2018-04-29 10:33:43.812 ERROR 540 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000388: Unsuccessful: insert into project (title, colour, description, project_user_id, bytes) values ('Test', '#F6D2B4', 'a short description of some project, making sure its over 50 characters', 1, pg_read_file('classpath:static/images/pon9s2N.jpg'))

2018-04-29 10:33:43.813 ERROR 540 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: column "bytes" is of type oid but expression is of type text
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
Position: 179
```

I've tried using the `CAST(pg_read... AS byte[])` but no luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pg_read_binary_file`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html) to read a binary file.

Comment: Gives me the following message: `2018-04-29 10:48:51.223 ERROR 412 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: column "bytes" is of type oid but expression is of type bytea`

Comment: An `oid` is an [object identifier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html)  A column of that type cannot contain an image.

Comment: how would you go about inserting the byta and inserting the oid into the column?

Comment: I'd change the [data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype.html) of the `bytes` column from `oid` to `bytea`